# Retrieve custom exception message from object setter in C#, ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I try to redirect user to an Error page when FormatException is thrown, and retrieve custom message generated in custom exception class. I need to use the exception caught in the origin (here: Product) class. I use the session state, to store the exception and retrieve the original one.

With below code I'm getting what I need, the only issue is that I cannot retrieve custom exception message, I just get:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

while I need to get custom message (without the original one).

I investigated various sources and ways of exception throwing, but I didnt come across a solution.

This is like an academic example I made. Here are my custom classes

**classes**

```
    public class Product
        {
            private int price;
            public int Price {
                get { return price; }
                set
                {
                    try
                    {
                        price = value;
                    }
                    catch (FormatException e)
                    {
                        throw new CustomException();
                    }
                }
            }

            public Product(int price) {
                this.Price = price;
            }
        }


    public class CustomException : FormatException
    {
        public CustomException() : base() { }
        public override string Message
        {
            get
            {
                return "Exception caught!";
            }
        }
    }
```

**code behind**

```
public partial class Input : System.Web.UI.Page{
            protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
                Product product = new Product(Convert.ToInt32(txt.Text));
            }
    }

    public partial class ErrorPage : System.Web.UI.Page{
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Exception err = Session["LastError"] as Exception;
            if (err != null)
            {
                err = err.GetBaseException();
                lblError.Text = err.Message;
            }
        }
    }
```

**global.asax file**

```
    <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" 
Inherits="ExceptionTest.Global" Language="C#" %>

    <script runat="server">
        void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e){
                Exception err = Server.GetLastError();
                Session.Add("LastError", err);}

            void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e){
                Session["LastError"] = "";}
    </script>
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exception is thrown when you try to convert to `Int32` and never reached to your `try-catch` block. If you want to test your `CustomException`, try this

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    try {            
       Product product = new Product(Convert.ToInt32(txt.Text));
    }
    catch (FormatException e)
    {
        throw new CustomException();
    }
}
```

**Update:**

If you really need to check at your `Product` class, you need convert your text there. (But it is bad idea. Convert to expected type as soon as possible)

Your code will be something like:

```
public class Product
    {
        private int price;
        public int Price {
            get { return price; }
            set
            {
                 price = value;
            }
        }

        public Product(string price) {
                                try
                {
                    this.Price = Convert.ToInt32(price);
                }
                catch (FormatException e)
                {
                    throw new CustomException();
                }

        }
    }
```

Your "code behind":

```
public partial class Input : System.Web.UI.Page{
        protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            Product product = new Product(txt.Text);
        }
}
```

Comment: @ Orifjon, many thanks! Your response made me realize the difference

Answer (score 0):

Use [Html Encode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to sanitize your Error message.

```
 public partial class ErrorPage : System.Web.UI.Page{
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Exception err = Session["LastError"] as Exception;
            if (err != null)
            {
                err = err.GetBaseException();
                lblError.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(err.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```